# equivalent for regexp /<rr>(.*?)</rr>/<test>$1</test>/gi

Tags: c, regex

I want to write simple program in C equivalent to the regular expression:

```
/<rr>(.*?)<\/rr>/<test>$1<\/test>/gi.
```

Does anyone have examples?

Comment: If you really want to do it - do it! Don't hold your horses!

Comment: Any reason you don't want to just download a regex library?

Comment: Why would you want to do that in C? String manipulation in C is not "simple". Also, seconding Mike's comment: download a regex library.

Answer (score 0):

It helps if you understand what the regex is supposed to do.

#### The pattern

The parentheses `(...)` indicate the beginning and end of a group. They also create a backreference to be used later.

The `.` is a metacharacter that matches any character.

The `*` repetition specifier can be used to match "zero-or-more times" of the preceding pattern.

The `?` is used here to make the preceding quantifier "*lazy*" instead of "*greedy.*"

The `$1` is likely (depends on the language) a reference to the first capture group. In this case it would be everything matched by `(.*?)`

The `/g` modifier at the end is used to perform a global match (find all matches rather than stopping after the first match).

The `/i` modifier is used to make case-insensitive matches

#### References

- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), [Grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), [Dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html), [Repetition: `*+?{…}`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)